# raise ValueError("Unsupported Lambda runtime {}".format(runtime))

Tags: node.js, docker, lambda, visual-studio-code

Has anyone had this error recently?

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\lambda_container.py",
>   line 65, in **init**
>       raise ValueError("Unsupported Lambda runtime {}".format(runtime)) ValueError: Unsupported Lambda runtime nodejs12.x

If so, how did you solve it?

So far I have tried uninstalling aws-sam-cli and reinstalling. Then I tried the same with Docker.

I have checked that the runtime for is set to nodejs12.x for each lambda function.

It gets thrown when I try to debug any lambda function locally in vscode. Up until about 2 weeks ago I was able to debug. All I find when I Google the problem are various references to the fact that "On 18th November 2019, AWS published they are now supporting Node.js 12.x runtime in AWS Lambda".

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to help me.

Comment: Error sounds like it's saying node12 is _not_ supported, try a different node version?

Comment: I thought the same but AWS says it has been supported since November and this has only been an issue in the last couple of weeks...

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-node-js-12/

Comment: That may be true, but the error says it's not supported. Are there any local dependencies that you need to update to get the support for node 12x?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything to point me in that direction. Plus it worked with 12x a couple of weeks ago, so something has obviously changed in my environment since then...

Answer (score 7):

AWS Sam released a new version v1.21.0 just 30 minutes after you asked the question.

I recommend you upgrade again now that version and try again.

Here are the release notes for that version: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/releases/tag/v1.21.0

One of the reasons it is not working is you may be using lambda edge, which doesn't support runtime node 12.x yet.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: I just upgraded my aws-sam-cli to the latest version and this is version 0.43.0. Am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Upgrading sam version solved it for me. Thanks